# Oracle Apex Generate valid wwv_flow_api.id

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

We want to dynamically build applications (regions and items), so we think we need to generate valid ids (p_id => ?) such that items can reside into regions (p_item_plug_id => ?).

Any clues?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the public package `WWV_FLOW_ID` to generate IDs. The ID returned here is used to populate all internal IDs for APEX related items. This will generate unique IDs for your dynamic scripts and not cause any issues when defining applications normally.

```sql
select WWV_FLOW_ID.NEXT_VAL from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what was needed!

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark the answer as the correct answer so others are not spending time unnecessarily coming up with alternate answers.